# Query: select between dates and display based on day

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my desired output on a webpage:

Monday:

1. bla
2. bla

Tuesday

1. bla
2. bla
3. etc..

The following query gives me this desired output but only for 1 day (today):

```
    $dag = mysql_query("SELECT x,x FROM x WHERE user_id = $id AND DAY(datetime)='13' AND MONTH(datetime)='4' ORDER BY TIME(datetime)");
```

However, this is not sufficient because I want to do this for all days between a range of dates, for example a full week ago up untill today.

How would I make such a query?

Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE datetime BETWEEN start AND end`

Answer (score 0):

Simple

your where clouse in your sql:

where (DAY(datetime)<'14' AND MONTH(datetime)='4') and (DAY(datetime)>'1' AND MONTH(datetime)='4') and user_id = $id

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't perfectly clear.

I think you want something like this:

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%W') weekday, 
            DATE(datetime) calendar_day,
            x,x 
       FROM x 
      WHERE user_id = $id
        AND datetime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        AND datetime <  CURDATE()
```

That will get you the rows with `datetime` values starting a week ago and ending yesterday.  Beware using `BETWEEN` for this purpose.

**Please** don't use the `mysql_` interface from php.